# Is it possible to script Windows GPO configuration tasks?

Tags: windows-7, script, group-policy

I have a login script on my domain that is configured through Group Policy Management (Start -> Administrative Tools -> Group Policy Management), as per this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7ojj.png), logged on to a Windows 7 desktop as a domain administrator.

I'd like to avoid having to do this by hand. Is it possible to script this somehow ?

Comment: Yes. See [Group Policy Management Console Scripting Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Scripting Group Policy tasks using GPMC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784365%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for some examples.

Comment: I saw that but it seemed like a bit of a learning curve. I was hoping for a simple solution but if delving in to that is the only way then that's what I'll have to do...

Comment: See [User Group Policy - Logon Scripts](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/w2k3/gp/group_policy_logon_scripts.htm). The page [Logon Scripts - With VBScript](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/logon_scripts.htm) has some you can start with ...

Comment: Interesting links, thanks. However they fall back to the same issue [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/w2k3/gp/group_policy_logon_scripts.htm#Logon%20Scripts) and [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-logon-script.htm#Assigning_Logon_Script_to_Group_Policy) - using the GUI to *wire up* the scripts to the GPO. I have working logon scripts already, it's that last step I want to write a script for so that it isn't necessary to manually perform GUI tasks...

Comment: Use a batch file wrapper as per [Bat - An Alternative Wrapper for Logon Scripts](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-logon-script.htm#.Bat_-_Alternative_Wrapper_for_Logon_Scripts)?

Comment: it'd still need wiring up though...

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com. Maybe someone there is better able to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21498/discussion-between-starfry-and-davidpostill).